# Left Join and conditional where not giving desired result?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, where-clause

I dont know how to freame this question. But read the description.
I have two tables as below,

EntityProgress table-

```
 EntityID       CurrentStateID
   101             1154
   201             1155
   301             1155
```

EnityApprovar Table

```
 EntityID        StateID        ActorID
   201             1154            8
   201             1154            9
   201             1155            8
   301             1154            8
   301             1154            9
   301             1155            9
```

Now What I want is if I pass the `ActorID=2` as parameter then  it should return only one row as below, Because we dont have any matching enityID in the `entityapprovar` table.

```
   EntityID      CurrentStateID     
    101              1154
```

But If I pass the `ActorID=9` then it should give me the result as below,

```
   EntityID      CurrentStateID
      301            1155
```

Because we have the entityID matching record in the `EntityApprover` table and also for that entityID we have the currentstateID and for that we have the actorid as 9.

So to get the result I have done as below,

```
 SELECT
      E.EntityID,
      E.CurrentStateID
 FROM 
      EntityProgress E LEFT JOIN EntityApprover EP 
      ON E.EntityID = EP.EntityID AND E.CurrentStateID = EP.StateID
 WHERE
     -- some conditions
     AND ((ISNULL(EP.ActorID,0) )= 0 
           OR ((ISNULL(EP.ActorID,0))!= 0 AND EP.ActorID = @ActorID AND Ep.CurrentStateID = E.StateID))
```

BUt When I pass the 2 I get the first result but when I pass the 9/8 I dont get the desired result. May be this is simple but I am stuck with it. I need some one others view to give me different way. 
    IN case of the confusing feel free to leave the comment.

Comment: When LEFT JOIN, put the right side table's conditions in the ON clause to get true left join behavior. (When in WHERE, you get inner join result.)

Comment: @jarlh I didn't get what you meant. Can you explain a bit or any pointer or links ?

Comment: A regular inner join means that rows from both tables that satisfies the ON clause are returned. When left join, also rows from the left side table that not satisfies the ON conditions are returned - and here NULL's are returned for the right side table. If your WHERE clause includes "regualar" conditions on those NULL values, the WHERE will be false and nothing returned, i.e. you're back at inner join result!  However, maybe those ISNULL's take care of this? (I don't know how they work...)

Comment: @jarlh IT returns me the true left join result that is with null values I am using that result in conditional where to get what i want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my attempt to answer you.

**Query**

```
DECLARE @ActorID int = 2

DECLARE @EntityProgress table
(
    EntityID int,
    CurrentStateID int
)

DECLARE @EnityApprovar table
(
    EntityID int,
    StateID int,
    ActorID int
)

INSERT into @EntityProgress
    values (101, 1154),
            (201, 1155),
            (301, 1155)


INSERT into @EnityApprovar
    VALUES (201, 1154, 8),
            (201, 1154, 9),
            (201, 1155, 8),
            (301, 1154, 8),
            (301, 1154, 9),
            (301, 1155, 9)

SELECT
    E.EntityID
    ,E.CurrentStateID
    ,EP.ActorID
FROM @EntityProgress E
LEFT JOIN @EnityApprovar EP
    ON E.EntityID = EP.EntityID
    AND E.CurrentStateID = EP.StateID
WHERE ((EP.ActorID IS NULL AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @EnityApprovar WHERE ActorID = @ActorID))
        OR (EP.ActorID = @ActorID))
```

When you pass `@ActorID = 2` then it'll give below output.

```
EntityID    CurrentStateID  
101          1154
```

And when you pass `@ActorID = 9` then it'll give below output.

```
EntityID    CurrentStateID
301         1155
```

Which is as expected you want.

Comment: Just a small change: Please replace the OP's `ISNULL(EP.ActorID, 0) = 0` with a simple `EP.ActorID IS NULL` :-)

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to include a `not exists` in the query as the row that you are trying to exclude when passing in 9 has no information to determine that there are other rows in the table that match.

i.e.

```
SELECT
      E.EntityID,
      E.CurrentStateID
 FROM 
      EntityProgress E LEFT JOIN EnityApprovar EP 
      ON E.EntityID = EP.EntityID AND E.CurrentStateID = EP.StateID
 WHERE ((ISNULL(EP.ActorID,0) = 0 
   and   not exists(select 1 
                      from EnityApprovar ep2 
                     where ep2.ActorID = @ActorID ))
    OR  (ISNULL(EP.ActorID,0) != 0 
   AND   EP.ActorID = @ActorID  
   AND   E.CurrentStateID = Ep.StateID))
```

Comment: Does not give the desired result. And also if the first condition is true then there will be no record for that entity in that table so not exists may not work in this case

Comment: Actually it does give the desired result as stated in your question for both 2 and 9 as inputs.

Comment: The accepted answer uses the same logic, it's just more simplified. No reason to downvote.

Answer (score -1):

Your lookup table for ActorId should be your query's starting point. If there's none in your schema (which I doubt), you can try this as a starting point. Using T-SQL syntax:

```
    DECLARE @ActorID int
    SET @ActorID = 2

    SELECT * FROM
         (SELECT @ActorID AS EntityId) 
    Actor
    LEFT JOIN
    EntityApprover EA
    ON Actor.EntityId = EA.EntityId ...
```

And from there you can extract the other column values.

Comment: How is this anything remotely related the question asked.